# Getting certain characters in a textbox

Tags: c#, calculator

Let's say I wanted to create a simple calculator, and I have it set up so whenever you press one of the operation buttons (`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`), it sets whatever you have in the textbox as the first number and then add the operation to the textbox. Now if I wanted the second number to be set to whatever is after the operation (`+`,`-`,`*`, or `/`) when I press the solve button, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you provide us some example of your code? Or something you have done already?

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the string `Split` method to get your factors like this:

```
string calculation = "5+1";
string[] factors = calculation.Split('+');
//factors[0] == 5
//factors[1] == 1
```

To handle string splitting on multiple operands use:

```
string calculation = "4+8-2";
string[] factors = calculation.Split(new char[] {'+' , '-' });
//factors[0] == 4
//factors[1] == 8
//factors[2] == 2
```

Comment: @StephenFleece you're welcome! Please mark this as the answer if it resolved your issue.